# Removing Text from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Have some real trouble removing some text from the home page of my SharePoint site. I've been told it's a breadcrumb that needs removed and I've tried a few methods they haven't worked and I don't think it is a breadcrumb.

However whenever I open up page editor I can't seem to interact with it, needless to say this isn't my day job!

Text in question.

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I hit edit page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override CSS file by adding .ms-core-pageTitle{Display:none !Important;}

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/47f10498-d72a-446d-9b26-840fb89f9142/how-to-hide-site-title-in-sharepoint2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Does that need to be contained within a <style> tag or something similar? Very not sure on this one!

Comment: Yes, if you going to add the style in master page, is necessary add <style>.
within a <head>
<style>
.ms-core-pageTitle{Display:none !Important;}
</style>
or you can refence external css that contains the css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">